# Template method of non-template class is not instantiating

Tags: c++, templates, g++, linker-errors

I have a non-templated class with which I wish to use templated methods, with some specialisations.

However, when compiling, the linker complains about the lack of the non-specialised template methods, though it has no trouble with the specialised ones.

In more detail, here is my (minimal reproducible example) header file `a.h`, with the templated function and a single `bool` specialisation:

```cpp
namespace xyzzy {
    class Aaa {
        public:
            Aaa();
            template<typename T> void do_fn(T item);
            template<bool> void do_fn(bool item);
    };
}
```

And here is the implementation of all that in the file `a.cpp`:

```cpp
#include "a.h"
#include <iostream>

namespace xyzzy {
    Aaa::Aaa() {
        std::cout << "constructor\n";
    }

    template<typename T> void Aaa::do_fn(T item) {
        std::cout << "do templated " << item << "\n";
    }

    template<> void Aaa::do_fn(bool item) {
        std::cout << "do bool " << item << "\n";
    }
};
```

The way in which I'm using it, from `amain.cpp`, is as follows:

```cpp
#include "a.h"

int main() {
    xyzzy::Aaa aaa;
    aaa.do_fn<bool>(true);
    //aaa.do_fn<float>(4.4);
}
```

That works fine (with that `float` call commented out) and I see the following output:

```
constructor
do bool 1
```

However, when I uncomment that line, the linker fails because it appears to have not generated that variant of the function, as per the following transcript:

```bash
pax@river-styx$ g++ -o amain amain.cpp a.cpp && ./amain
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cchgn0gc.o: in function `main':
amain.cpp:(.text+0x48): undefined reference to `void xyzzy::Aaa::do_fn<float>(float)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I thought templates were meant to magically appear when you use them so I suspect I'm doing something wrong in letting the compiler know that I need it.

It's *possible* the fact that I've got the code in the `cpp` file is preventing the creation of templated function when the header is included by the main program, and the object generated from `a.cpp` has only the stuff known to be needed. So putting it in the header *may* fix this but I was trying to avoid putting any implementation in the header at all.

How do I go about fixing this? If implementation-n-header is the only way, I can do that, but it seems somehow less than perfect in terms of encapsulation.

I'm running `g++ (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.2) 9.4.0` by the way.

Comment: [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file) perhaps? Works fine all in one here: https://godbolt.org/z/83Tzf8xzf

Comment: [Works here](https://onlinegdb.com/tF9_dDrCc).

Comment: @user12002570: it works there because the problmatic line is still commented out. When you uncomment it, you get the same problem.

Comment: @RetiredNinja: that looks like it might be the answer. I may have to explicity define the templated function in the `a.cpp` file so that they're available to everyong. Will check ...

Comment: If you want to make it so someone looking at the header just sees a clean interface and not a bunch of inline code you could put the template functions in another non-compiled file "stuff.inl" or something like that and include it as the last line of the header.

Comment: @RetiredNinja: it looks like the method in that answer does work, I just have to add `template void Aaa::do_fn<float>(float item);` declaration to `a.cpp` and it creates the templated method in the object file, based on the non-specialised template. (I'm not keen on the "private" header since the implementation is still visible so I won't try that one. Hence this is probably a dupe so, unless someone complains bitterly, I'll delete it in an hour or so ... Thanks for your help, BTW, much appreciated.

Comment: f you know the types you need then explicit instantiation works great and potentially stops folks from trying to jam the wrong type in there. We stopped using the inline files and just implement the functions in the same file after the class definition. Was a pain to juggle multiple files and at the time it was hard to get syntax highlighting and formatting working reliably in all the editors we used. You'd spend more time copy/pasting back into the header to edit and then back before you saved.